# Web api bad encoding on IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke

Why I get this symbol  � instead of ąčęėįš.
I pass parameter via Ajax. On chrome works fine, but on IE its not working.

Ajax:

```
var comment = document.getElementById("commentstext").value;
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'charset=utf-8',
    url: url,
    data: "state=false&comment=" + comment
});
```

api:

```
[DnnAuthorize()]
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("insert")]

public void InsertRecord(bool state, string comment)
{
       ...
}
```

url: `http://.../API/Rate/insert?state=false&comment=ąčęąčę`

IE version: 11 and 9

Chrome version: 33 and 46

Now I cann't test other browser

Its work after i add this: `comment = encodeURIComponent(comment);`

Comment: Can you confirm which IE version(s) you're testing with. Also, you mention Chrome, but does it work in other browsers? (Firefox, Safari, etc?)

Comment: You should read this if you don't understand what  � is: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I know that is. But how solve this problem I don't know. Iam already set  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: if there's an issue with the response then have you considered what your DNN Module sends back to see if its UTF-8 encoded?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var comment = document.getElementById("commentstext").value;
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: { 
        state: false,
        comment: comment
    }
);
```

And also specifying UTF encoding in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
    ...
</system.web>
```